# How do I get my AlertDialog to fill parent width

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm building an alert dialog dynamically with an edit text field with two buttons. The dialog box is only wrapping the width which is very small, I want it to stretch to fill the parent width

```
public void showMessageDialog(String name){

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    this.etMessage = new EditText(this);
    etMessage.setText("");
    alert.setMessage("Message " + name);
    alert.setView(etMessage);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Message", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            updateLocation();

        }
    });
    alert.setNeutralButton("Map", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            showMap();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it from code, but if you inflate a view from XML, you can add the `layout_width="fill_parent"` attribute to the top level view, and it should fill the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

You can then inflate the view like so:

```
View dialogLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
```

and add it to the AlertDialog.Builder:

```
builder.setView(dialogLayout);
```

Comment: Yeah but the dialog box doesn't exist on the xml sheet. I don't even think a dialog element exists.

Comment: Nope, but you can instantiate any view, and add it to the AlertDialog.Builder. Added more to answer to help you out.